# Multiple update laravel with checkbox (LARAVEL 5.2)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, checkbox, laravel-5

I want to update the class data on the students I've selected. But I have constraints that the student data I have selected has not been successfully updated correctly.
What is the error in writing my code?

The first I have a student table:

```
{!! Form::open(['method' => 'POST', 'action' => ['SiswaController@pindah_kelas']]) !!}
  <div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading" align="center">Daftar Data Siswa</div>
    <table id="dataSiswa" class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th><input type="checkbox" name"select-all" id="select-all" />
          <th>NIPD</th>
          <th>NISN</th>
          <th>Nama Siswa</th>
          <th>Kelas</th>
          <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <?php foreach($data_kelas as $siswa): ?>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox" value="{{ $siswa->id }}"></td>
          <td>{{ $siswa->nipd }}</td>
          <td>{{ $siswa->nisn }}</td>
          <td>{{ $siswa->nama_siswa }}</td>
          <td>{{ $siswa->kelas->nama_kelas }}</td>
          <td>
            <div class="box-button">
              {{ link_to('siswa/' . $siswa->id, '', ['title' => 'Detail', 'class' => 'btn btn-info btn-sm glyphicon glyphicon-list']) }}
            </div>
            <div class="box-button">
              {{ link_to('siswa/' . $siswa->id . '/edit', '', ['title' => 'Edit', 'class' => 'btn btn-warning btn-sm glyphicon glyphicon-edit']) }}
            </div>
            <div class="box-button">
              {!! Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE', 'action' => ['SiswaController@destroy', $siswa->id]]) !!}
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" title="Hapus"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></button>
              {!! Form::close() !!}
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach ?>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  {!! Form::submit('Pindah Kelas', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary form-control']) !!}
  {!! Form::close() !!}
```

This is my code javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#select-all').click(function(){
      if(this.checked) {
        $(':checkbox').each(function(){
          this.checked = true;
        });
      }
      else {
        $(':checkbox').each(function(){
          this.checked = false;
        });
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

And the second this is my Routes:

```
Route::get('siswa/pencarian_siswa', 'SiswaController@pencarian_siswa');
Route::resource('siswa', 'SiswaController');
Route::post('siswa', 'SiswaController@pindah_kelas');
```

The last i have controller:

```
public function pindah_kelas(Siswa $siswa, Request $request)
{
  $input = $request->id;
  $siswa->update($input)->whereIn('id', $input(['id_kelas' => 3]));
  Session::flash('flash_message', 'Data Siswa Berhasil Diupdate.');
  return redirect('kelas');
}
```

My question is how do I update the transfer of students from the current class into another class from the student data I have selected?
I am very grateful if you can help me in solving this problem

Comment: one possible solution can be on update delete previous data of last time checked check-boxes and insert new

Comment: where is this $request->id coming from ? i don't see a form input that have a name 'id'

Answer (score 0):

first you're update is wrong .. it should be like

```
$siswa::whereIn('id', $request->checkbox)->update(['id_kelas' => $request->id]);
```

this will update the id_kelas of all records that was checked in the checkboxes to the `$request->id` value .. i don't know where you will get that in your code but i think that's your goal ..

another error is it will only work for the first checkbox for you are closing the form in the loop .. the code will assume that the form ends there ..

Comment: ErrorException in Grammar.php line 118:
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, string given, called in C:\wamp64\www\stpbapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\Grammar.php on line 376 and defined

Comment: can you `dd($request->checkbox);` to see it's value